# Angular CLI command to skip creating the SCSS file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The following command in Angular CLI generates a new component with 3 files - HTML, TS and SCSS.

```
ng g c file --skip-import --spec false
```

I just need the HTML and CSS. I'm already skipping the spec file.. How do I tell it to skip creating the SCSS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular / create a module, component without css file in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234958/angular-create-a-module-component-without-css-file-in-one-command)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the option inlne styles, e.g.

```
ng g c file -is -spec false
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Following angular command  can be used in the terminal

```
ng g c something-component --flat -it -is --skipTests


     -is for inline css, preventing style file creation>
     --flat to prevent folder creation
     -it for inline template, preventing html file creation
     --skipTests to prevent .spec file creation
```

Try one of them as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit your `angular-cli.json` file to tell angular to create `css` file instead of `scss`

Open your `angular-cli.json` file from the root folder of your project.

Find the *defaults* key

```
...

"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
}

...
```

and change the value of `styleExt` to `css`.

You should be good to go now.

Answer (score 0):

To skip test and style files you can use following `Angular` command.

**The Command:**

```
ng g c topbar --skip-tests true --style none
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ng g c component-name --skip-tests --style none
```

for future reference: you can issue `ng g c --help` to show all options regarding generating components

(edit: I reread your question, if you want to force create css instead of scss, use `--style css` instead)