# Angular / create a module, component without css file in one command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

Is there such an option to create a Module that is linked to a component, which does not have a css file upon creation?

e.g.

The default way of doing this for me so far is the following:

`ng generate module name`
/
`ng generate component name`

And I get the basic structure of a component:

`name.component.css
name.component.html
name.component.spec.ts
name.component.ts
name.module.ts`

And I want to create the following with only **ONE** query:

`name.component.html
name.component.spec.ts
name.component.ts
name.module.ts`

e.g. something like:

`ng g m name + c name - css` ... you get the idea.

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 47):

Minimalist Angular Cli generate example

`ng g c hero-component --flat -t -s --skip-Tests`

- `-s`          for inline css, preventing style file creation
- `--flat`       to prevent folder creation
- `-t`          for inline template, preventing html file creation
- `--skip-Tests`  to prevent .spec file creation

Link to the Angular doc reference https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

With all these parameters together,

The cli creates a single .ts file in the current folder and links it in the module.

Comment: can this be configured globally for the app in angular.json ?

Comment: When getting "Error: Unknown argument: skip-Tests" use lower case skip-tests

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ng generate -is` for `inline-style`, which will not generate css file separately, but will keep css inside component (inline).

Comment: I get the following response:

`ng generate -is
Schematic "-is" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
Error: Schematic "-is" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
    at SchematicEngine.createSchematic ........`

Comment: `ng g c component -is` and I get a `node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install` `, needless to say, it is not empty, and I ran npm install again, but it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The latest, correct answer is:

```
ng g c MyComponent --style none
```

It will NOT create style file and it will NOT have any inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Although late, But this might help geeks who already have a created component (in my case 'abc') having

```
 1. abc.component.html
 2. abc.component.css
 3. abc.component.spec.ts
 4. abc.component.ts
```

and not using other files than abc.component.ts Then can delete the other 3 files and modify abc component's @Component decorator to

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-abc',
  template: ``,
  styles: []
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting the "style" property to "none", Angular CLI will not generate any style files (CSS, SCSS, etc.) when you create a new component using the Angular CLI commands like ng generate component.

angular.json

```
    {
     ...
     "projects": {
         "your-project-name": {
         ...
             "schematics": {
                 "@schematics/angular:component": {
                     "style": "none"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     ...
    }
```